# F# compose pattern matched function

Tags: f#, composition

I have these types:

```
  type ShouldRetry = ShouldRetry of (RetryCount * LastException -> bool * RetryDelay)
  and RetryCount = int
  and LastException = exn
  and RetryDelay = TimeSpan

  type RetryPolicy = RetryPolicy of ShouldRetry
```

Now I want composability of the retries; something like this:

```
let serverOverloaded = [| exnRetry<TimeoutException>;
                          exnRetry<ServerBusyException> |]
                       |> Array.map (fun fn -> fn (TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4.0)))

let badNetwork = [||] // etc

let compose p1 p2 =
  // http://fssnip.net/7h
  RetryPolicy(ShouldRetry( (fun (c,e) ->
    let RetryPolicy(ShouldRetry(fn))  = p1
    let RetryPolicy(ShouldRetry(fn')) = p2
    let (cont, delay) = fn c,e
    if cont then cont, delay 
    else
      let (cont', delay') = fn' c,e
      cont', delay') ))

let finalPolicy = serverOverloaded |> Array.scan compose (RetryPolicies.NoRetry())
```

But I'm getting compiler errors on `fn`, `delay` and `fn'`, saying "The value or constructor 'fn' is not defined".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see two problems in your `compose` function.

When decomposing `p1` and `p2`, the pattern needs to be wrapped in parentheses (otherwise, the compiler interprets the code as a definition of `RetryPolicy` *function*, instead of pattern matching):

```
let (RetryPolicy(ShouldRetry(fn)))  = p1 
let (RetryPolicy(ShouldRetry(fn'))) = p2
```

When calling `fn'` a bit later, you need to pass it the arguments in a tuple (otherwise, the compiler thinks that you're calling `fn'` with just a single argument `c` and then building a tuple):

```
let (cont', delay') = fn' (c,e)
```

I didn't check (or tried to run) the whole example, so I don't know if the rest of the code does what you want.